# Vector class library: solivng a problem while using vec4d

Tags: c++, simd, avx, vector-class-library

here a piece of simplified code that causes me a problem/error (Vec4d is coming from the Agner Fog library  VCL)

```
#define AVX256_ALIGNED_MALLOC(type,size) (type *)_aligned_malloc(size * sizeof(type),32)
#define AVX256_FREE(ptr) _aligned_free(ptr)

int N = 1024;
std::vector<double> A(N);
double* Aaligned = AVX256_ALIGNED_MALLOC(double, N);
memcpy(Aaligned, &A[0], N * sizeof(double));

int N4=N>>2;

for(size_t i = 4; i <N4-4; ++i)
{
    //....
    ... = ((Vec4d*)(Aaligned - 1))[i] + ((Vec4d*)(Aaligned))[i] + ((Vec4d*)(Aaligned + 1))[i];
}

AVX256_FREE(Aaligned);
```

If it is clear to me that I'am allowed to use

```
((Vec4d*)(Aaligned))[i]
```

Can you confirm that I cannot use

```
((Vec4d*)(Aaligned-1))[i]
```

or
((Vec4d*)(Aaligned+1))[i]
Any hints ?
Many thanks.
Luc

Comment: The misaligned access may fail, depending on how the compiler implements it. Use Vec4d().load, rather than Vec4d().load_a if you want to use misaligned data.

Comment: You can find aligned container classes for the Vector Class Library at https://github.com/vectorclass/add-on/tree/master/containers

Comment: Is it even safe to point a `Vec4d*` at some `double[]` data?  `__m256d` is defined as `__attribute__((may_alias))`, but `Vec4d` isn't, so that's a strict-aliasing violation.  Use load intrinsics like `_mm256_loadu_pd`, or the `.load` member function.  Also, use an aligned allocator on your `std::vector<double, custom_allocator>` if you really want alignment, or just use unaligned loads on your std::vector directly.  Definitely don't allocate + memcpy!

Comment: Thanks for these hints.
May the instruction "load" suffer from a disabling calculation time compared to the casting operation (Vec4d*) ?
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for these hints. May the instruction "load" suffer from a disabling calculation time compared to the casting operation (Vec4d*) ? Put another way, does "load" perform a copy or does it simply wrap a memory buffer ? Thank you

Comment: @Luc. The load function does the same as accessing the array with a pointer, at least when compiling for release mode.